# Custom Collections from generic to specific

Tags: c#, collections

I have the following generic custom collection:

```
public class XList<Object> : List<Object>
{
    public XList() : base()
    {

    }
    public XList(Object[] values) : base(values)
    {

    }
    public void Add(XList<Object> inputObjects)
    {
        if (inputObjects == null) { return; }
        if (inputObjects.Count == 0) { return; }
        foreach (Object currentObject in inputObjects) { Add(currentObject); }
    }
}
```

I successfully use this collection and it's generic methods with many data types. For example:

```
XList<int>
XList<String>
XList<XFolder>
```

(XFolder is a custom class which refers to a folder)

Now I want to embed a method to the above class which is **specific for an XFolder list**. For example a method which sorts folders from longest to smallest path. Do I have to create a new custom collection or can I do it in the above class, so that I retain its generic properties/methods?

EDIT: To avoid misunderstanding

@ Matt Burland: I don't mean a heterogeneous collection. A heterogeneous collection is a collection which stores different data types in the same collection. Each collection of what I have in mind stores the same type of data in the same collection, but can store different types of data in different collections (of the same type, namely XList).

My problem is that I want to be able to execute different methods for each collection according to their type:

A collection of integers should have math methods (add all the numbers for example)

A collection of Strings should have string methods (sort strings alphabetically for example)

A collection of Foods should have methods which apply to foods (group them by food type)

I would like to be able to do the following in my main program:

```
XList<int> myNumberList = new XList<int>; myNumberList.Add(....//fill list with integers
XList<String> myStringList = new XList<String>; myStringList.Add(....//fill list with strings
XList<Food> myFoodList = new XList<Food>; myFoodList.Add(....//fill list with foods

int sumOfNumbers = myNumberList.sum();
myStringList.sort();
XList<Food> mySweetFoodList = myFoodList.getSweets();
```

In this example all of my collections are XList collections. But they have different methods according to their types:

XList has a sum() method

XList has a sort() method

XList has a getSweets() method

I don't know if this is possible. I don't even know if I am thinking it right. For the moment I stick with JaredPar's answer and use an XListExtension

Comment: `I have the following generic custom collection` Generic? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You may want to use something other than `Object` to identify your generic parameter. Maybe `TObject`.

Comment: Yes you should use generics, if you then want more visibility over the  type T have a look at constraints : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: @GiorgioMinardi - Care to provide an example of how constraints could help here?

Comment: By saying generic I mean that it is a list of Object, which could specifically be an int, String or other object types. The methods of the class works for any of them. But what if I want to create methods which work for a specific object type only?

Comment: @M.Babcock , yes I've said a silliness :) - by reading -specific- I immediately thought about constraints. And yes this would make it more specific for an xfolder but less for other types. -1 for me!

Comment: @StefanosKargas: Do you really mean a generic collection or a heterogeneous collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have a specific sorting method for `XList` instances which are instantiated with the `XFolder` type.  This is a great case for using an extension method

```
public static class XListExtensions { 
  public static SortFolders(this XList<XFolder> list) {
    // Do the sort
  }
}
```

I wouldn't use inheritance here to solve the problem.  The sorting method doesn't represent a new type of object but instead represents a specialized behavior for a specific instantiation.

Additionally I would avoid deriving from `List<T>` entirely here.  The sample you've shown doesn't create a new type of list with overridden behavior.  It simply adds a few specialization methods on top of it.  Choosing an extension method here allows the behavior to be used on all `List<T>` values.

Answer (score 2):

If the method is doing something specific to `XFolder` it should not be in the generic base class. YOu should one of the following:

You can create a specialized class:

```
public class XFolderList : XList<XFolder>
{    
    // put your XFolder specific method here    
}
```

Or you could create an extension method:

```
public static class XFolderExtensions
{    
    public static void SpecialXfolderMethod(this XList<XFolder> list)
    {
       // do special things here, change the return type if you need to
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an IComparable on XFolder, you could just have your XList always sort. Or, have an XSortedList that always sorts if you don't want your XList to. This only solves the sorting, so if you need more additions in the future, the extension method or specialized class may be the way to go.